# Need a column to auto increment based on another with trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, auto-increment

I have a simple table. It has 5 columns, two of which are `job_num` and `line`.  I would like to leave the line number blank on insert and possibly use a trigger to insert a "1" if there are no other lines with that job number.  If there is a `job_num` already with a line then it would take the next line number.

These are my columns

```
`job_Num` int,
`line` int ,
`Description` nvarchar(60),
`qty` int,
`price` int
```

Comment: unless you are in a extremely busy system you probably don't want to try and maintain line in that manner but rather generate it on the fly when querying results by using something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_NUM ORDER BY someIdOrDate)  if supported by RDBMS

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sequence. For example,

`CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_1 START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 49999999 NOCYCLE;`

2. Create a trigger with the sequence.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI_1 BEFORE
   INSERT
     ON table_name FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SELECT
     SQ_1.NEXTVAL
   INTO
     :NEW.column_name
   FROM
     DUAL;
   END
   ;
   ```
3. Insert a record and there you can see the effect.